# can't read output from command: standard output was redirected - TCL

Tags: tcl, stdout, stderr

I am trying to execute a TCL file from another TCL file.
Example: FileA.tcl is executing FileB.tcl

FileA.tcl has these commands:

```
open {|FileB.tcl >& FileB.log &}  #Executing FileB as a background process
```

I get this error message: `can't read output from command: standard output was redirected.`

Also how to capture file descriptor?

Comment: Why are you using `open` instead of `exec`?

Comment: When exec &, If the main script fileA.tcl is killed, the background job fileB.tcl will be running.

Comment: What file descriptor(s) do you want to have open between the parent process and the child process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are typically three file descriptors used to communicate between a parent process and a child process. These are the child process's `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` (in theory there can be others but it's totally non-standard).

By default, if you do `exec THING` then the `stdin` is from `/dev/null` (or equivalent on Windows), the `stdout` is a pipe connecting back to the parent process that will become the result of the `exec`, and the `stderr` is a pipe connecting back to the parent process that will become the error produced by the `exec` (if anything's written there).

If there's an `&` at the end, then the subprocess is run disconnected from the parent process; `stdout` defaults to going to the parent's real `stdout` and `stderr` defaults to going to the parent's real `stderr`.

If you use `open |` (which uses the same subprocess launching engine as `exec`) then you take control over more of that yourself. In particular, when `open |` is in read mode (default) then `stdin` is still from `/dev/null`, but `stdout` is the pipe that is the result of `open |` and `stderr` is collected and will produce an error when you `close` the main pipe. (If you want to control `stdin` then you need a non-default open mode, and you can have things bidirectional if you open using a read-write mode. Bidirectional pipes can be a little tricky with buffering and a bit of care is needed to avoid blocking due to all the bits and pieces operating semi-independently.)

All of that is modified by what redirections you use.

Relevant sections of [the documentation](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.html) are:

> `>& fileName`
> Both  standard output from the last command and standard
> error from all commands are redirected to the file named
> *fileName*, overwriting its previous contents.

> If  the  last  arg  is  "`&`" then the pipeline will be executed in background.  In this case the **exec** command will return a  list  whose  elements  are  the  process identifiers for all of the subprocesses in the pipeline.  The standard output from the last command  in  the  pipeline will  go  to the application's standard output if it has not been redirected, and error output from all of the commands in the pipeline  will go to the application's standard error file unless redirected.

---

In your case, you've got:

```
open {|FileB.tcl >& FileB.log &}
```

That's in pure read mode (`stdin` is from `/dev/null` by default) and has both `stdout` and `stderr` redirected to a file. And is backgrounded. That means there's no pipe there to read from, and no way to interact with the child process at all (other than using the process ID if you could get that). `open` rejects that; it wants to return you a pipe! If you want such a disconnected child process, use `exec`.

```
exec FileB.tcl >& FileB.log &
```